# Cannot connect to SQL Server Express but I can with SQL Management Studio

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I have launched a SQL Server Express container via docker-compose. This launches all fine and I can connect with my locally installed SQL Management Studio using the credentials. But when I try to connect from R, I get the following error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 01000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen
> (Connect()).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: sql-server
    container_name: sql-server
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=foobar
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
    volumes:
     - mssqldata:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  mssqldata:
```

I use the following connection code in R:

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver   = "SQL Server",
                       Server   = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS",
                       UID      = "sa",
                       PWD      = "foobar"
)
```

Is anybody aware of a setting within SQL Server Express that needs to be set to allow access from R or something along those lines?

Comment: [Here](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/#ms-sql-express) they also specified the Database besides the driver and teh server.

Comment: @danlooo that doesn't seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: Try to spin up e.g. mysql docker container to see if R is able to connect to any ODBC connection.

Comment: From where is the R code executing? From the Docker host? Another Docker container? Or inside the same Docker container as the SQL Server instance?

Comment: Aside... the SQL Browser service, required for instance name resolution, is unsupported on Linux and so unsupported in Docker containers. Instead of `Server = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS"` you might have more luck with `Server = "tcp:localhost,1433"` or similar.

Comment: I tend to use `server="127.0.0.1,1433` on linux and windows and it works for me, none of `\sqlexpress` or `tcp:` (which might be useful but can work without).

Comment: Beside the remark of @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY about using no instance name, you might want to check your password. It needs to comply with the SQL Server password requirements, otherwise authentication fails.